# What is the difference between Behaviors.setup and Behaviors.receive in Akka Typed?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-typed

In the Akka tutorials i sometimes see

```scala
Behaviors.setup { ctx =>
 ...

 Behaviors.receiveMessage[String] { msg =>
  ... // some operations with ctx and message  
 }

}
```

and sometimes just

```scala
Behaviors.receive[String] { (ctx , msg) =>
  ... // some operations with ctx and message  
}
```

What is the difference?

Comment: take look to the differences between the functional style and the object oriented style: https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/style-guide.html#functional-versus-object-oriented-style

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function (`ActorContext[String] => Behavior[String]`) passed to `Behaviors.setup` is executed when the actor is spawned, regardless of whether there's a message to process.

The function (`(ActorContext[String], String) => Behavior[String]`) passed to `Behaviors.receive` is not executed until there's a message to process.

Note that if you had

```
Behaviors.setup { ctx =>
  // code block A

  Behaviors.receiveMessage[String] { msg =>
    // code block B
  }
}

Behaviors.receive[String] { (ctx, msg) =>
  // code block A
  // code block B
}
```

`code block A` in the `Behaviors.receive` would execute with every message (unless and until a new `Behavior` was installed by `code block B`).